# удаляются файлы при деплое

Tags: git, github, deploy

пробую сделать деплой через ftp но почему то удаляются файлы на удаленном сервере, которые находятся в гитигноре, пробовал на другом репозитории, там не удаляются, не могу понять в чем причина

```
on: push
name: Deploy website on push
jobs:
  web-deploy:
    name: Deploy
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Get latest code
        uses: actions/checkout@v2

      - name: Sync files
        uses: SamKirkland/FTP-Deploy-Action@4.0.0
        with:
          server: ftp.ultimatefreehost.in
          server-dir: htdocs/
          port: 21
          protocol: ftp
          username: name
          password: pass
          exclude: .git/**
```

Comment: ftp не имеет никакого отношения к git-у

Comment: Но вообще в описании к FTP-Deploy-Action английским по белому написано, что он **синхронизирует** содержание папки и репозитория. В том числе удаляет файлы. Если хотите что бы что-то не удалялось, добавьте это в поле `exclude`.